# The Gnome desktop slows down over time in UbuntuGNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, performance, ubuntu-gnome, restart, animations

I am having an annoying problem in Gnome/Gnome-Shell. After some time, like an hour or two, suddenly windows starts moving slower and jerky. When I drag them around they move in steps instead of smoothly. Same thing with maximize and restore, the animations are are jerky and significantly slower. It's like the CPU or graphics card is throttled but I do not see any indication that is the case, and I do not have any process hogging CPU or memory either.

All applications run normally as long as I do not move them around. I have also disabled all extensions. If I restart GNOME with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> r everything is back to normal. For a while that is. I do not have that problem with Unity, but I prefer GNOME so I would like to find out what is going on. Ideas?

Comment: What graphics card do you use and what driver?

Comment: In my case, Gnome-shell's memory usage would keep increasing until the system crashed. I left an empty, fresh Gnome session at night and it was frozen by morning.

Comment: This is a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro with Intel HD Graphics 5300. This only happens  in GNOME. Unity is fine.

Comment: As for memory usage I do not see anything unusual there. Not in the CPU usage either. I suspect the video drivers, but why only in GNOME and not in Unity on the same machine?

Comment: I have the exact same issue also with Intel GPU (Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller). It's not problem just with Ubuntu.

Comment: I have this problem in 18.04. Your temporary solution was helpful.

Comment: Has a permanent solution been found? Is this an actual bug in Gnome?